# How to implement a function with Python(Sympy), realizing the same as '_' and replacement rule in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: python, math, wolfram-mathematica, sympy

In Wolfram Mathematica, I can define named patterns where `_` (called [Blank](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)) matches any expression and then use the match in a [replacement rule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html).

An example:

```
    testexpr = p1[MM]*p2[NN] + p1[XX]*p2[MM] + p1[XX]^2;

    FunTest[expr_] := Expand[expr] /. {(p1[l1_]*p2[l2_]) -> FF1[l1]*FF2[l2], 
    p1[l1_]^n_ -> 0, p2[l1_]^n_ -> 0}

    FunTest[testexpr]
```

The result is `FF1[XX] FF2[MM] + FF1[MM] FF2[NN]`

However, I don't know how to use sympy in Python to do the same thing.

```
    import sympy as sp

    p1 = sp.IndexedBase("p1")
    p2 = sp.IndexedBase("p2")

    FF1 = sp.IndexedBase("FF1")
    FF2 = sp.IndexedBase("FF2")

    MM,NN,XX=sp.symbols('MM NN XX')
    SSlist=[MM,NN,XX]

    testexpr=p1[MM]*p2[NN] + p1[XX]*p2[MM] + p1[XX]**2 

    def FunTest(expr): 
        expr=expr.subs([(p1[SS]*p2[SS2],FF1[SS]*FF2[SS2]) for SS in SSlist 
        for SS2 in SSlist]+[(p1[SS]**2,0) for SS in SSlist]+[(p2[SS]**2,0) 
        for SS in SSlist],simultaneous=True)
    return expr

   rest=FunTest(testexpr) 
   print(rest)
```

So the result is also `FF1[MM]*FF2[NN] + FF1[XX]*FF2[MM]`.

But I want to know if there is an easy way to make it more general, as in Wolfram  Mathematica. If SSlist is a large list and there are many different variables, it will be a difficult to implement with my solution.

> I wonder whether there is an easy way without writing a loop over the whole list, **for SS in SSlist**, as in Mathematica. Can someone familiar with sympy give me any hints?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I have found out one solution to my own question. It works out as I want. Instead of using subs(), I use wild operator and replace().

```
   import sympy as sp
   p1 = sp.IndexedBase("p1")
   p2 = sp.IndexedBase("p2")

   FF1 = sp.IndexedBase("FF1")
   FF2 = sp.IndexedBase("FF2")

   MM,NN,XX=sp.symbols('MM NN XX')
   SSlist=[MM,NN,XX]

   SS = sp.Wild('SS')
   SS1 = sp.Wild('SS1')

   testexpr=p1[MM]*p2[NN] + p1[XX]*p2[MM] + p1[XX]**2 

   replacements = {p1[SS]*p2[SS1] : FF1[SS]*FF2[SS1], p1[SS]**2: 0, p2[SS]**2 : 0}

   def replaceall(expr, repls):
       for i, j in repls.items():
           expr = expr.replace(i, j, map=False, simultaneous=True, exact=False)   
       return expr

  rest=replaceall(testexpr,replacements) 
  print(rest)
```

The result gives exactly the same as I did before:

```
  FF1[MM]*FF2[NN] + FF1[XX]*FF2[MM]
```

One thing I want to know is this efficient when there are many symbols because of the for loop. It seems that the two methods are similar, just the one I found recently looks more concise.

I would like to know whether there is a more general way to do such things as Wolfram Mathematica does.

Any comments are welcomed. Thanks!